# Installed programs list software?

Tags: 18.04, updates, 20.04, lts, installed-programs

Anyone know of a good program or way to list Programs/Softwares installed, wanting to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 but need a list of the things I've installed so I can reinstall them on 20.04?

Comment: You haven't said if this is a desktop or server, but you can `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade your system (see the release notes https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes), OR you can re-install without format, and it'll note your additional packages before it erases system directories, installs, then adds back your additional packages if available for the new system (eg. Qt4 reached EOL in 2019 so those apps if noted ported to Qt5 are gone & won't be found..).  ie. options exist already.

Comment: its desktop ubuntu not server